# GetAllCampaignTargets not returning any targets [JAVA - Sandbox V201109]

Tags: google-ads-api

I am facing this issue when migrating the Google API from V201101, V13 to V201109

I am trying to get all the targets using GetAllCampaignTargets
provided in the [link](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#9RD3n1d8sRQ/trunk/examples/v...google-api-adwords-php%7Cgoogle-api-adwords-python-lib%7Cgoogle-api-adwords-dotnet%7Cgoogle-api-adwords-ruby%7Cgoogle-api-ads-ruby%7Cgoogle-api-adwords-perl&sa=N&ct=rx&cd=2).

For the campaign i added, i am seeing targets in "Google Sandbox
Viewer" but in output object of GetAllCampaignTargets i am seeing
totalNumEntries value as 6 but in actual entries object only 1 is
available with null targets.

Could you please help me to sort out the issue.

Thank you
Balaji

Answer (score 0):

The official forum of AdWords API is http://groups.google.com/group/adwords-api. I recommend that you ask the question there, since the official developer of the PHP library regularly answers questions on the forum. Also, turn on the SOAP logging (the settings are in src/Google/Api/Ads/AdWords/settings.ini), and POST a sanitized SOAP request and response xml for the failing request. Someone will answer your question in a day or two. Make sure you sanitize the xml before posting, do not provide email, password, authToken, developerToken, etc.

Cheers, Anash